# unexpected output in javascript when converting string to number

Tags: javascript, numbers, parseint, type-conversion

In MDN in [this example on parseInt method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Using_parseInt)

```js
console.log(parseInt(4.7 * 1e22, 10)); // Very large number becomes 4
console.log(parseInt(4.7 * 1e20, 10)); //result is 470000000000000000000
```

or small number than 20 it give me expected result what is reason for this ?

Comment: `4.7 * 1e22` is already an integer. Why are you parsing that as an integer again? `parseInt` converts the first argument into a string (because it expects one) and parses that as an integer again. The actual result of `4.7 * 1e22` is `4.7e+22`.

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: ok i got it but also there is conflicting in converting
 4.7e+22 why this give 4 and 4.7e+2 give 470

Comment: The answer to the question, "why can some values be accurately represented and other, larger numbers, not is because of how the variable storage is allocated in memory. There is a maximum value that can be stored for a Number type in javascript as discussed here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER. The reason this is a comment and not an answer is because the number the second line puts out is, in fact, larger than that and I am not sure why. I am interested to hear the answer as well.

Comment: expected result for me is to 47000000000000000000000 not just 4

Comment: `4.7e+2` _is_ just `470`. Read about IEEE 754 Doubles and the ECMAScript spec. The behavior of numbers is specified there.

Comment: @Xufox I read the spec on parseInt: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-parseint-string-radix and I still don't know exactly. It has something to do with having more than 20 digits. `parseInt` replaces them with zero's. Also if I do `parseInt(1e22)` I get 1. If we substitute that in `parseInt(4 * 1e22)`. You would get `parseInt(4 * 1)`. Which explains the result, but this is not actually how `js` works. Would love a better explanation if you have one.

Comment: `parseInt` is pretty straight-forward. The more interesting thing is how numbers get stringified, i.e. how the `toString` method behaves on numbers.

Comment: I think I get it. The `1e20` value is being `stringified` to a large number, including 0's, then parsed. While the `1e22` is being `stringified` to exactly this string: `4.7e22`. `parseInt` doesn't care because there's a dot in there. It will happily parse this to `4` as well: `parseInt("4.7e20")`. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

With help from @Xufox

```
console.log(parseInt(4.7 * 1e22, 10)); // Very large number becomes 4
console.log(parseInt(4.7 * 1e20, 10)); //result is 470000000000000000000
```

What's happening here in steps:

- Calculation is done (4.7 * 1e20) and (4.7 * 1e22)
- Result of calculation is `stringified` by the JavaScript engine so it can be passed to `parseInt`
- The string is parsed back to a number
- Finally it's logged

JavaScript truncates every number with more than 20 digits using the scientific notation. That means the result of the calculations are:

- 470000000000000000000
- 4.7e22

These are stringified before being passed to `parseInt`:

- "470000000000000000000"
- "4.7e22"

These are strings, not numbers. `parseInt` will now ignore everything after the dot in the second value and return `4`.

Answer (score 1):

It fails after 20 digit integer number with radix 10.

You may have a look to the description of [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Description):

> Because some numbers include the e character in their string representation (e.g. **`6.022e23`**), using parseInt to truncate numeric values will produce unexpected results when used on very large or very small numbers. `parseInt` should not be used as a substitute for [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor).

From the standard ECMA 252 V 5.1 [15.1.2.2
parseInt (string , radix)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2)

Step 13:

> Let *mathInt* be the mathematical integer value that is represented by *Z* in radix-*R* notation, using the letters **A-Z** and **a-z** for digits with values 10 through 35. (However, if *R* is 10 and *Z* contains more than 20 significant digits, every significant digit after the 20th may be replaced by a **0** digit, at the option of the implementation; and if *R* is not 2, 4, 8, 10, 16, or 32, then *mathInt* may be an implementation-dependent approximation to the mathematical integer value that is represented by *Z* in radix-*R* notation.)
>
> ...
>
> NOTE
>
> `parseInt` may interpret only a leading portion of *string* as an integer value; it ignores any characters that cannot be interpreted as part of the notation of an integer, and no indication is given that any such characters were ignored.

```js
var x = 5.7 * 1e20;
console.log(x);
console.log(parseInt(x, 10));

x = 5.7 * 1e21;
console.log(x);
console.log(parseInt(x, 10));
```